# ASP.NET Error 404. When is a resource temporarily unavailable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My ASP.NET WebForm app is running fine in debug. However, after deploying it to DEV server, it frequently throws error 404: The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I know the resource (whatever it is) couldn't have been removed or had its name changed, because refreshing the page a few times gets the app running again, but the same problem pops up again every now and then, and it's annoying.

So my question is, assuming that the resource is temporarily unavailable, what could be the cause(s) of this, and how to fix? Thanks..

Comment: Have you checked your IIS log for errors? Are there any steps in the deployment process that you may be skipping on accident such as restarting the app pool in IIS?

Comment: Is it the page that 404s or something it consumes?

Comment: Thanks Chad, the deployment process seems fine to me. However, I'm not sure how to check if I'm restarting the app pool in IIS by accident. Could you please advise?

Comment: NikolaiDante, I'm assuming it's the page. The suggestion is: Please review the following URL (****.aspx) and make sure that it is spelled correctly.